# How to import newsletter subscribers user csv in magento

Tags: magento, csv, import, newsletter

I have `csv in which have lot of email is exit`,it want to `assign those email to newsleter subscription list`. Who i will do....

And `check how skip for exiting customer because there are already list in newsleter`

Comment: Add import.php file in root directory also csv file and csv filename is subscribers.csv and inside code is same check

Comment: are you have single store ya multi store

Comment: this code only import email and status

Comment: you can managed store from csv file and import.php file code

Comment: you can not put answer on question section.Please   put it in answer section.

Comment: i have edit and update question and put you code in answer.As you  did not get  privilege for answer so, i have put your code instead of you

Comment: Go attempt...  if you get above 10 reputation at stackoverflow then you can put answer.I have up vote your question  for  getting  5 reputation to you.Please accept my answer and you get 2 pint more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As **krupal patel did not have enough reputation for post answer so , instead of him  i have put answer.**

Follow this step

**Step 1** Add `import.php file in Magento root directory` this code  should be

```
     <?php
    $store_id = 1;
    $csv_filepath = "subscribers.csv";
    $csv_delimiter = ',';
    $csv_enclosure = '"';
    $magento_path = __DIR__;
    require "{$magento_path}/app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
    echo "<pre>";
    $fp = fopen($csv_filepath, "r");

    if (!$fp) die("{$csv_filepath} not found\n");
    $count = 0;

    while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, 0, $csv_delimiter, $csv_enclosure)) !== false){
        if ($count != 0){

            $email = trim($row[1]);
            $type = trim($row[2]);
            $fname = trim($row[3]);
            $lname = trim($row[4]);
            $status = trim($row[5]);
            $website = trim($row[6]);
            $store = trim($row[7]);
            $store_view = trim($row[8]);

            if (strlen($email) == 0) continue;
            echo "$email";
            $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
            if ($subscriber->getId()){
                echo $email . " <b>already subscribed</b>\n";
                continue;
                }

            Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->setImportMode(true)->subscribe($email);
            $subscriber_status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);

            if ($status == 1){
                  $subscriber_status->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                  $subscriber_status->save();
                }else if($status == 2){
                  $subscriber_status->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
                  $subscriber_status->save();
                }else if($status == 3){
                  $subscriber_status->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED);
                  $subscriber_status->save();
                }else if($status == 4){
                  $subscriber_status->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED);
                  $subscriber_status->save();
                }
                echo $email . " <b>ok</b>\n";
            }

        $count++;

        }

echo "Import finished\n";
```

**Step 2** `Add subscribers.csv` file in `Magento root directory`

**Step 3:** `Run import.php file` in root directory like ( `http://domainname.com/import.php` )

**Step 4:** Go to admin menu `Newsletter > Newsletter Subscribers and finally you subscriber user CSV file import`

Visit link for code = http://krupalpatel92.blogspot.com/2014/09/magento-newsletter-subscriber-csv-file.html

Cheer up krupal patel

Comment: I have update this code for import user email with status. also update CSV file format

Comment: Thaks Amit bera you can visit updated code here http://krupalpatel92.blogspot.in/2014/09/magento-newsletter-subscriber-csv-file.html